# Is a serialized object portable?

Tags: c#, serialization

In my C# application I saved class objects by serialization. Now I have a binary file on my disk. Is this file portable in the sense that installations of the same application on other systems will recognzie it? Are there disadvantages to consider?

Comment: Which serializer did you use? *all* files are binary ;p

Comment: @Marc: But some more so than others!

Comment: @Marc You're right :-) With binary, I wanted to highlight that I used the BinaryFormatter class.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood "binary serialization" != `BinaryFormatter`; there are other serializers that also write non-text data. Important distinction, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the exact same version of the app, then pretty much any serializer will be happy. When you start iterating versions, then assuming you are using `BinaryFormatter`, you can start hitting version compatibility issues, particularly if you have refactored (moved / renamed types, moved / renamed fields, etc). Which is why I strongly recommend *not using* `BinaryFormatter` for persistence. If you just want the data stored, there are a wide range of other serializers that will work great; `XmlSerializer`, Json.NET, protobuf-net, `DataContractSerializer`, etc - which all handle versioning more gracefully than `BinaryFormatter`. If you specifically want binary for performance reasons (large files, etc), then protobuf-net may be worth a look (but I'm biased). Otherwise, you could simply use compression - xml and json compress pretty well.

Additionally, note that `BinaryFormatter` will not work *at all* between other platforms, or *generally* even on other .NET frameworks (including the mobile frameworks, etc).

Comment: Great - thank you for the detailed answer. I will give XmlSerializer a try. It seems easy to use and my data is not too big.